# string error in jsonify(results) - Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, string, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working with a flask app that queries my sqlite db and pulls out info on number of disease cases in each state in each year.  The route below pulls the correct data, but for some reason, will print not out the strings such as "Cases_2010", "Rate_2010, etc" that are in the request.  Is this is problem with the string itself or the concatenation?  It does print the "State" string, just not any after that.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, desc
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json
import numpy as np
import os


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///westnile_1.sqlite")

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

Disease_Data = Base.classes.disease_data 

session = Session(engine)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return(
        f"Welcome to the West Nile Virus Case Report API <br>"
        f"Available routes: <br>"
        f"/api/v1.0/Cases_per_year_2010_2017 <br>"
        f"/api/v1.0/case_totals <br>"
        f"/api/v1.0/json_combined <br>")


@app.route("/api/v1.0/Cases_per_year_2010_2017")
def cases_2010_2017():

    results_10 = session.query("State: " + Disease_Data.State, "Cases_2010: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2010, "Rate_2010: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2010,
        "Cases_2011: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2011, "Rate_2011: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2011,
        "Cases_2012: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2012, "Rate_2012: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2012,
        "Cases_2013: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2013, "Rate_2013: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2013,
        "Cases_2014: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2014, "Rate_2014: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2014,
        "Cases_2015: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2015, "Rate_2015: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2015,
        "Cases_2016: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2016, "Rate_2016: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2016,
        "Cases_2017: " + Disease_Data.Cases_2017, "Rate_2017: " + Disease_Data.Rate_2017).all()     

    json2010 = json.dumps(results_10)

    return jsonify(results_10)
```

[results_10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB7vH.png)

[sqlite db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vTux.png)

[updated output of return jsonify (json2010)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MdQ4.png)

Comment: Does your table has same column name as State, Cases_2010? Then you can easily convert the result object which is infact a tuple into dict/json.

Comment: yes, column names in the tables are the same. how do I convert into dict/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have any info on ORM hence I am assuming Orm has the exact number of columns as the table has.

```
results_10 = session.query(Disease_Data).all() # This will return the list of Disease_Data objects
json_list= []
for result in results_10:
    temp_dict = result.__dict__
    temp_dict.pop('_sa_instance_state',None)
    json_list.append(temp_dict) 
    # OR
    # temp_dict = dict(result)
    # temp_dict.pop('_sa_instance_state',None) # removing unwanted key
    # json_list.append(dict(result)) #Either of two should work

json2010 = json.dumps(json_list)

return jsonify(results_10)
```

I could not test it on my local but should give an idea.

In case you want to keep the format of the data:

```
column_list = Disease_Data.__table__.columns.keys()
results_10 = session.query(Disease_Data).all() # This will return the list of Disease_Data objects
    json_list= []

    for result in results_10:
        temp_dict={}
        for col in column_list:
            temp_dict[col] = getattr(result,col) 
        json_list.append(temp_dict)
    json2010 = json.dumps(json_list)

return jsonify(results_10)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. When I tried the way above, it gave me a traceback error of: TypeError: Object of type 'InstanceState' is not JSON serializable.

Comment: updated the code. There can be elegant ways possible by iterating Table columns and assigning the values. Or create a function which does that and then append in the list while ignoring the key ''_sa_instance_state'. Hope it helps

Comment: will ignoring that keep the data in the right format? A little more insight: This data needs to stay pertained to each state because once this is a json file, I need to extend the properties key of a geojson file to include this information for each state. Then use the geojson to make my choropleth (final product).

Comment: value for '_sa_instance_state' key does not contain any useful data that you need to serialize.

Comment: Can I do that within the flask app? Or should I take the original tuple and work with it outside of the app (add the keys outside of the app).  The choropleth is being built in javascript.

Comment: Tried the updated code (for keeping the data in the same format), gave me this error unfortunately:     for result in results_10:
                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.  Tried all different sorts of indentations, same result.

Comment: thanks for the updated code.  Ran it, got the message:   temp_dict[col] = getattr(result,col)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

Comment: ran the code, switched the last line to return jsonify(json2010), received the updated out in "updated output of return jsonify (json2010)" link in the question. Now that it is a list of dictionaries, I should be able to use this to extend my state border geojson, correct? Will the slash marks make a difference? if so, I can remove those.

Comment: output of  `json.dumps(list_of_dict)` should be json string. You should be able to use it as you use other json string.